# Xamarin.Android video decoding and encoding example does not work when included in another project

Tags: c#, android, video, xamarin, xamarin.android

We are following [this GitHub project](https://github.com/leye0/XamarinAndroidMediaCodecSurfaceToSurface) to transcode video on Android with Xamarin. The project successfully transcodes video (no audio). However, when we copy the classes over to an existing Xamarin project and try to use them, it throws the custom runtime exception ("frame wait timed out") in this snip of code in OutputSurface.cs:

```
const int TIMEOUT_MS = 1000;

System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(_frameSyncObject);
while (!IsFrameAvailable)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Wait for onFrameAvailable() to signal us.  Use a timeout to avoid
                    // stalling the test if it doesn't arrive.
                    System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(_frameSyncObject, TIMEOUT_MS);

                    if (!IsFrameAvailable)
                    {
                        if (returnOnFailure)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        // TODO: if "spurious wakeup", continue while loop
                        throw new RuntimeException("frame wait timed out");
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    if (returnOnFailure)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    // shouldn't happen
                    throw new RuntimeException(ie);
                }
            }
IsFrameAvailable = false;

System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_frameSyncObject);
```

Here's the code that sets `IsFrameAvailable` to true which is set as an SurfaceTexture FrameAvailable event:

```
private void FrameAvailable(object sender, SurfaceTexture.FrameAvailableEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(_frameSyncObject);
            if (IsFrameAvailable)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("mFrameAvailable already set, frame could be dropped");
            }
            IsFrameAvailable = true;
            System.Threading.Monitor.PulseAll(_frameSyncObject);
            System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_frameSyncObject);
        }
```

Again, this does not happen when we run the sample project on the same device.

Similarly, we tested an [Android native project on GitHub](https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder). This includes very similar code but includes audio and is a Java project. We created a binding library and referenced it in our Xamarin project. It also throws this custom runtime exception.

It seems to be something with threading or blocking, but we can't quite figure it out. Why would the same code thread properly in project but not the other?

Please let me know if I can include any other information to help.